# PHP week day values from multidimensional array function

Tags: php, arrays

when a week is selected in my project, only the values of the week from Mon - Sun should be displayed.
After a short search I found this function, which gives exactly what I need.
I have tried to display the values from the array individually, but I always get an error.

```
function get_first_and_last_day_of_week( $year_number, $week_number ) {
    $today = new DateTime( 'today' );
    return  [
        'first_day' => clone $today->setISODate( $year_number, $week_number, 1 ),
        'last_day'  => clone $today->setISODate( $year_number, $week_number, 7 )
    ];
}

$day = get_first_and_last_day_of_week(2021, 39);

$day = print_r($day );

echo $day //alternative i tested: echo $test['first_day']['day'];
```

Example array output:

```
Array ( 
    [first_day] => DateTime Object 
        ( 
            [date] => 2021-09-27 00:00:00.000000 
            [timezone_type] => 3 
            [timezone] => Europe/Berlin 
        ) 
    [last_day] => DateTime Object 
        ( 
            [date] => 2021-10-03 00:00:00.000000 
            [timezone_type] => 3 
            [timezone] => Europe/Berlin 
        ) 
    )
```

For that i got the error:  `Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type DateTime as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\...:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on line 21`

and on the alternative i got the warning: `Warning : Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on line 21 Warning : Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on line 21`

How can i output the values from the array?

Comment: So given the input `2021, 39`, what should be the output?

Comment: I added the output of 2021, 39

Comment: No, I mean what is your _desired_ output? Day names, dates, day of year, etc.

Comment: my desired output is the date as value for my sql query and as output on the site

Comment: Something like this? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55df9d9aec40afa68548a50179bcbf3530532158

Answer (score 0):

If you only want access data, you can simply convert you object to a multidimentional array :

```
$dayArray = (array) $day;
```

Note that if you want an array only because you're unusual with PHP object, object value display are not so difficult, just different syntax :

```
$day->first_day->timezone
```

Is the same as :

```
$day["first_day"]["timezone"]
```